# CodingBat sum67: why is this solution wrong?

Tags: python

I'm working on the following codingbat problem:

> Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 7 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 7). Return 0 for no numbers.
>
> ```
> sum67([1, 2, 2]) → 5
> sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7]) → 5
> sum67([1, 1, 6, 7, 2]) → 4
> ```

My solution is:

```
def sum67(nums):
    sum = 0 
    throwaway = 0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if throwaway == 0:
            if nums[i] == 6:
                throwaway = 1
        elif throwaway == 1 and i > 0 and nums[i-1] == 7:
            throwaway = 0
        if throwaway == 0:
            sum += nums[i]
    return sum
```

I totally know this is not the best solution, but I'm just curious to know why this is wrong.  Could you please explain me why this is wrong and in which particular case it gives a wrong result?

Comment: Are you aware of the `bool` type?

Comment: `for i in range(len(nums))`? Eek!

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: "I totally [k]now this is not the best solution" -- there is little point in criticizing his style.  Apart from not being very "pythonic", there is nothing wrong with `for i in range(len(seq)):`

Comment: Thank you Ferdinand! Easy on me, guys! However, I do know `for i in range(len(seq)):` is not very pythonic, but I wanted to get the previous element of the list using `[i-1]`. Obviously this is not necessary, but I just wrote the first solution that came to my mind, without thinking much (as you can tell...)
The great Nick could have added a visible test like the one Ferdinand suggested: `sum67([6,7,6,7]) -> 0`, just to take my error into account. Have a good day guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your program has a bug. Check the results of the following:

```
print sum67([1,2,5])
print sum67([1,2,6,5,7])
print sum67([1,2,6,5,7,6,7])
```

This will print:

```
8
3
16 <-- wrong
```

If a 7 is followed by a 6 immediately, you will add the 6 and all following numbers. I'm not sure if more than one range of 6 ... 7 is allowed in the input, but if it is, you have to fix your algorithm.

This simple implementation does return correct numbers:

```py
def sum67(nums):
    state=0
    s=0
    for n in nums:
        if state == 0:
            if n == 6:
                state=1
            else:
                s+=n
        else:
            if n == 7:
                state=0
    return s
```

Besides, if you don't need to use an index for some obscure reasons, you can directly iterate over the elements of a list ( `for element in list: ...` ).

Comment: +1: Multiple 6-7 ranges are allowed (there are tests for that); the simplest test case that fails for the OP's solution would be `sum67([6,7,6,7]) -> 0`

Comment: Thanks man, I overcomplicated it without any reason: my solution would work if I added " and nums[i]!=6 at line 8, but obviously yours is much better.
Yes, I used an index because I wanted to access the previous element of the list, but as you show this is not necessary.

Comment: Actually you could make the `state` variable in my solution a `bool` (`True` or `False`), but the integer solution has the advantage that you can have more than two states and is, in my opinion, more educational. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 5):

Below is my solution for your reference:

```
def sum67(nums):
flag=False
sum=0

for num in nums:
    if(num==6):                  #Turn the flag on if the number is 6
        flag=True
        continue
    if(num==7 and flag is True): #Turn the flag Off when 7 is seen after 6
        flag=False
        continue
    if(flag is False):           #Keep on adding the nums otherwise
       sum+=num
return sum
```

Comment: Prob. will not want to shadow the built-in `sum` as variable name here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to that problem. As answered already, the issue is when a 6 occurs immediately after a 7. I solved this in a slightly different way, so I thought I'd post it.

```
def sum67(nums):
  total = 0
  i=0  
  while i < len(nums):
    if nums[i] == 6:
      while nums[i] != 7:
        i+=1
      i+=1
    if i<len(nums) and nums[i]!=6:  
      total+=nums[i]
      i+=1
  return total
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int sum67(int[] nums) {
 int sum=0;
  for(int i=0; i<nums.length ; i++)



{
          if(nums[i]==6)
               for(int k=i+1 ; k<nums.length ; k++ )
                  {if(nums[k]==7)
                                {i=k; break;}
                  }   
           else if(nums[i]==6) 
              sum=sum+nums[i];
          else
              sum=sum+nums[i];


  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
def sum67(nums):
    result = 0
    flag = True
    for num in nums:
        if num == 6:
            flag = False
        if flag:
            result += num
        if num == 7:
            flag = True
    return result
```

Comment: Very pythonic answer, prefer this one for its use of flags to trigger the exclusive range.

Answer (score 1):

This is my edit of @TheNeophyte code. I liked that solution because that's how I'd likely approach the problem. The only edit really was taking out the

```
if i<len(nums) and nums[i]!=6:
```

and just putting an elif statement without saying

```
i<len(nums)
```

since it's not needed again after the first while loop.

My edit below VVV

```
def sum67(anArray):
    arrTotal = 0
    n =0
    while n < len(anArray):
        if anArray[n] == 6:
            while anArray[n] != 7:
                n+=1
            n+=1
        elif anArray[n] != 6:
            arrTotal += anArray[n]
            n+=1
    return arrTotal
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, if the last element is a 7 you don't need to iterate through every element. The question states " ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 7 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 7)". Once you find a 6 you can simply check if the last element is a 7 and if so simply break out and return the sum; otherwise, you can continue to go through the remaining elements. This is helpful when working with a larger number of elements in an array. 
ex. [1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 2, 99, 99, 2, 99, 99, 2, 99, 99, 7]

My solution:

```
def sum67(arr):
    sum = 0
    tmp = 0
    for n in arr:
        if n == 6:
            tmp = 6
            continue
        if tmp == 6:
            if n == 7:
                tmp = 0
                continue
            elif arr[-1] == 7:
                break
            else:
                continue
        sum += n
    return sum
```

Comment: sum67([1,2,6,5,7,1,6,7]) does not fit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this I Know this is quite readable but not the best code:

```
def sum67(nums):
  offcount = False
  sum = 0 
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    if offcount == False:
      if nums[i] == 6:
        offcount = True
      else:
        sum = sum + nums[i]
    else:
      if nums[i] == 7 :
        offcount = False
  return sum
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:)

```
def sum67(nums):
    result = 0
    inside = False
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if not inside and nums[i] != 6:
            result += nums[i]
        if nums[i] == 6:
            inside = True
        if nums[i] == 7:
            inside = False
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum67(nums):
  sum = 0
  sumbrake = False

  for i in nums:
    if i != 6 and sumbrake == False:
      sum += i
    else:
      sumbrake = True

    if i == 7:
      sumbrake= False

  return sum
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach was to build a new list which consisted only of valid segments ie segments that **did not** start with a 6 and end with a 7 for that corresponding 6. Then I simply computed the sum of the elements of that new list. Worked perfect in the codingbat exercise platform

```py
def sum67(nums):
    lst =[]  #holds result after discarding invalid segments
    while 6 in nums:   # Continue until no more 6's found in nums segment
        #Find the first 6
        idx6 = nums.index(6)

        #Build list upto but excluding the first 6
        lst += nums[:idx6]
        
        
        #Find the next 7
        idx7 = nums[idx6:].index(7)  # this would be relative to nums[idx6:]
        
        #slice
        idx = idx6+idx7           # absolute position of 7 w.r.t nums
        nums = nums[idx+1:]       # slice from the position of the 7 to end
    lst += nums                   # takes care of any leftovers after the last 7
    return sum(lst)
```

Can be condensed to fewer lines of code but I wanted to maintain readability of code. I am wondering if there is a recursive way to solve this. Working on it.

Thanks everyone for your great alternate solutions

Answer (score 0):

## I know this isn't the best solution, but thought to share :

```
def detect67(nums):
  count = nums.count(6)
  pos6 = 0
  pos7 = 0
  sum1 = []
  for i in range (len(nums)):
    sum1.append(nums[i])  
    # if I do just sum1 = nums, they use SAME memory locations.
  #print ("Count=",count)
  for i in range (count):
    pos6 = sum1.index(6)
    pos7 = sum1.index(7)
  if pos7<pos6:
    sum1[pos7] = 0
    pos7 = sum1.index(7)

    del nums[pos6:pos7+1]
    del sum1[pos6:pos7+1]
    count = nums.count(6)
    if count == 0:
      return (nums)

  

  return (nums)


def sum67(nums):

 detect67(nums)
 sums=0
 if nums == []:
   return 0
 for i in range (len(nums)):
   sums+=nums[i]
 return sums
```

Comment: **NOTE**: This doesn't cover all use cases: sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7]) = *5*, yours gives 216

Answer (score 0):

here's my 6 liner answer.  Hope this helps

```
def summer_67(arr):
    s = 0
    for x in arr:
        if x not in range(6,7+1):
            s = s + x
    return s
```

Comment: The question was not asking for another solution to the problem, the question is asking why *his particular solution* doesn't work.

Comment: This doesn't cover all use cases: sum67([6, 7, 1, 6, 7, 7]) = *8*, yours gives 1

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use nested loops..

```
def sum67(nums):
    s=0
    flag=1
    for n in nums:
        while flag:
            if n!=6:
                s+=n
                break
            else:
                flag=0
        while not flag:
            if n!=9:
                break
            else:
                flag=1
    return s
```

Comment: Note: this is an incomplete solution; sum67([1, 1, 6, 7, 2]) = *4*, yours gives 2.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def sum67(nums):

    while nums.count(6) >= 1:
        list = (nums[0:nums.index(6)]) + (nums[nums.index(7)+1:len(nums)])
        nums = list
    return sum(nums)
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please give an explanation as to what your code is doing and why it answers the original question?

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum67(arr):
    for n in range (0, len(arr)):
        if arr[n] == 6:
            Sum1 = sum(arr[0:n])
            print ("Before 6 Sum Numbers:", Sum1)
    for k in range (0, len(arr)):
        if arr[k] ==7:
            Sum2 = sum(arr[(k)+1:])
            print ("After 7 Sum Numbers:", Sum2)
    if 6 and 7 in arr:
        print("Last Result")
        return (Sum1+Sum2)
    else:
        print("Last Result")
        return sum(arr)
```

Comment: 14 other answers to a question posted 7 years ago. Why is your solution unique or worthy of consideration? Without an explanation, it will most likely go ignored by those who are visiting this post looking for help.

Comment: **NOTE**: This doesn't cover all use cases: sum67([1, 6, 2, 2, 7, 1, 6, 99, 99, 7]) = *2*, yours gives 19.

Answer (score 0):

simplified code without while and for loop :

```
    def summer_69(arr):
        pos6 = 0;
        pos9 = 0;
        newArr = [];
        if 6 in arr:
            pos6 = arr.index(6);
        if 9 in arr: 
            pos9 = arr.index(9);
        if 6 in arr and 9 in arr : 
            newArr =  arr[0:pos6] + arr[pos9+1:len(arr)];
        else:
            newArr = arr;
    return sum(newArr);
    pass
```

Comment: tbh, this doesn't solve the problem, and also the question criteria is different from that expressed here. You are required to exclude values within major [6....7] boundaries of the array. Try revisiting the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a more Pythonian approach?

```
def sum67(arr):
    if (6 in arr):
        i1 = arr.index(6)
        i2 = arr[i1:].index(7)
        res = sum(arr[0:i1]+arr[i1+i2+1:])
    else:
        res = sum(arr)
    return res
```

Comment: This solutions doesn't cover all cases: sum67([1, 6, 2, 6, 2, 7, 1, 6, 99, 99, 7]) = *2*, returns 213 instead. Also, sum67([6, 7, 1, 6, 7, 7]) = *8*, returns 21 in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 13 line answer, which uses List index positions to exclude values enclosed by every [6..7] pair.

**Technique**: Return the sum of array elements upon subtracting the (sum of) excluded elements.

```py
def sum67(nums):
  idx_list=[]  
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i]==6:
      c_6 = i    # index pos of 6
      j = c_6+1   # counter to find index position of 7
      while nums[j]!=7:   # stop search when 7 spotted in list
        j+=1
      c_7 = j    # index pos of 7
      idx_list += list(range(c_6,c_7+1))  # list of index position(s) of elements to be excluded

  idx_main = list(set(idx_list))   # set() removes repeated index positions captured while looping
  del_val = [nums[i] for i in idx_main]
  return sum(nums)-sum(del_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def sum67(nums):
    sum=0
    sum6=0
    for n in nums:
        sum+=n
    if nums.count(6) >= 1:
       a=nums.index(6)
       b=nums.index(7)+1
       nums67=nums[a:b]    
       for i in nums67:
           sum6 += i 
    return sum - sum6
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//stackoverflow.com/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: HI Amin, Thanks for contributing thats what this site is made from. Collaboration and contribution. Just like when writing code an aim is to provide answers with maximum readability. That been said then adding code snippets even if just sudo code. Try using the code snippet option (""). Many thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This may not the best solution , but its simple and gave correct output all cases

```
def sum67(nums):
  sum = 0
  i = 0
  while( i < len(nums)):
    if nums[i] == 6:
       while(nums[i] != 7):
         i += 1
    else:
      sum += nums[i]
    i += 1
  return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a short and efficient (O(n) time, O(1) space) alternative, using an iterator:

```
def sum67(nums):
    it = iter(nums)
    return sum(x for x in it if x != 6 or 7 not in it)
```

This mainly sums the values. But whenever a 6 is encountered, the `7 not in it` consumes all values until the next 7 (and it's false, so none of the values from that 6 to that 7 make it into the sum).

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum67(nums):
    c=0
    state=True
    for i in nums:
        if state:
            if i==6:
                state=False
            else:
                c+=i

        else:
            if i==7:
                state=True
    return c
```

Comment: Please give an explanation of your code or comment it at appropriate places so that others may easily understand your code. An answer is no good if other people have a hard time understanding it.

Comment: Hi Abhishek. Here is my explanation. initially the counter is 0. and state is true. now the counter is incremented until the 'i' is matched with number 6. if it matched with 6, the state is changed to false. now the iteration  directly jumps to to else statement (as the statement is False. now the iteration continues until the 'i' is matched with number 7(and this is the part where we are ignoring the numbers from 6 to 7) once i is matched with 7, the state is then changed to True. and this continues on and on...! hope this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_69(arr):
    x=arr.index(6)
    y=arr.index(9)
    if 6  not in arr:
        return sum(arr)
    else:
        sum1=arr[:x]
        sum2=arr[y+1:]
        sum3=sum1+sum2
        return sum(sum3)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum67(nums):
  
  cnt = 0
  ignore = False
  for num in nums:
    if not ignore and num == 6:
      ignore = True
    
    if not ignore:
      cnt = cnt + num

    if ignore and num == 7:
      ignore = False
  
  return cnt
```

Comment: Please add descriptions to your code answers

Answer (score 0):

Here is the shortest solution I have seen for this question:

```
def sum67(nums):
  while 6 in nums: 
    del nums[nums.index(6):nums.index(7,nums.index(6))+1]
  return sum(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my solution, I activate and deactivate with a boolean when a 6 starts and a 7 ends. While in the "active == True" state, the code still functions normally except now there's a "temp_count". If the array reaches a 7, the "temp_count" will be subtracted from "count".

```
def sum67(nums):
  count = 0
  temp_count = 0
  active = False
  
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    count += nums[i]
    
    if nums[i] == 6:
      active = True
      
    if nums[i] == 7 and active == True:
      active = False
      count = count - temp_count - 7
      temp_count = 0
      
    if nums[i] == 6 or active == True:
      temp_count += nums[i]
      
  return count
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works well too.

```
def sum67(nums):
    total1 = 0
    total2 = 0

    for y in range(0, len(nums)):
        if nums[y] == 6:
            total1 = nums[0:y]

        if nums[y] == 7:
            total2 = nums[y + 1:]

    total = total1 + total2
    return sum(total)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

def sum67(nums):
while 6 in nums:
x = nums[nums.index(6):nums.index(7)+1]
for i in x:
nums.remove(i)
return(sum(nums))

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is find sum of sublist[6,...7]. Then take sum of list subtract sum of sublist to find sum of otherwise.

```
def sum67(nums):
    sum_67 = 0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == 6:
            for i2 in range(i+1,len(nums)):
                if nums[i2] == 6:
                    nums[i2] = 0
                if nums[i2] == 7:
                    sum_67 = sum_67 + sum(nums[i:i2+1])
                    break
    return sum(nums) - sum_67
```

Answer (score -1):

may be this will help you:

```
def sum_67(arr):
    while 6 in arr:
        del arr[arr.index(6):arr.index(7)+1]
    return sum(arr)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.